# Monitor Apache PHP FPM and restart on down

Tags: php, bash, apache, ssh, cpanel

I'm using the cPanel for hosting my website.
Sometimes my website throws Error 503 due to error related to php fpm

```
[proxy:error] [pid 32549] (111)Connection refused: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/c31dac5ed583d707687865fef34d1a67.sock (*:80) failed

or

[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 32549] [client 20.40.43.219:64380] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

It happens mostly when traffic spike due to unknown hits/bots/crawlers/dos attack etc.

What I want to achieve is whenever my apache throws an error which are due to

> **Connection refused: AH02454:**

or

> **AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS**

My php fpm restart command runs the shell script.

I have a similar script for apache, in which it restarts if http process exceed 300

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
service="httpd"
count="$(ps aux | grep -c "$service")"
logfile="/opt/httpd/autostart-apache2.log"
restart(){ systemctl restart  "$service" ; }

if (( count > 298 )); then
  echo "starting apache at $(date)" >> "$logfile"
  restart >> "$logfile" 2>&1
else
  echo "$count Apache processes is running at $(date)"
fi
```

Can someone help me to create a script for this??
What the script will do is

1. Tail watched the apache error log = tail -f apache error log
2. check for string "AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS"
3. If string matches, restart php fpm = systemctl restart ea-php74-php-fpm.service
4. If there isn't then echo php-fpm count to output log

Comment: I had come to realization it is happening due to php-fpm pid files automatically getting deleted from the 
```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/
```
Generally this folder has 3 files.. .sock, symlink, .pid files.. but that php-fpm.pid file automatically getting deleted from it and then website throws 503 error